# hoverIntent not working

Tags: hoverintent

I've been battling with this for ages now, just can't seem to get it right.

The hoverIntent plugin isn't working, but hover is.

Here it is on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDcL4/16/).

Comment: Please define what you mean by "isn't working". Describe what you want to happen, and what's actually happening.

Comment: @ebohlman When I hover over the button, the panel should slide down. It works when using "hover". But I need to use hoverIntent so that the panel doesn't keep sliding down everytime you accidentally mouse over the button. At the moment, when I use hoverIntent, absolutely nothing happens. The panel doesn't slide down at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem that everyone has when using hoverIntent, which is why I generally try to avoid it.

I had the same problem initially, hover() from JQuery doesn't work same way as [Brian Cherne](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)'s hoverIntent(). It requires **two** functions (instead of a choice of one or two): one for hovering in and one for hovering out. Since you defined the object to slidedown, you have to define what it should do once the user hovers his/her mouse out. If you don't want it to do anything, you can create a dummy function function(){}. You may have to change other components in your html too.

Here's a similar post: [jQuery hoverIntent not working, but hover does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518974/jquery-hoverintent-not-working-but-hover-does)

Make sure you also have your javascript files implemented correctly and in the correct directory. Hope this helps!