# hoverIntent with iframe, messes up with border and height. hover works

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

I've seen this already: [jQuery hoverIntent not working, but hover does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518974/jquery-hoverintent-not-working-but-hover-does)

However, I DO have two handlers for in and out, and hoverIntent still doesn't work. Hover does. I'm positive I have all the directories right as well.

```
var sidebar = $('#sidebar');

    sidebar.hoverIntent(function(){
        sidebar.attr('id','sidebar_active');
    }, function(){
        sidebar.attr('id','sidebar');
    });
```

The sidebar is an iframe:

```
<iframe id="sidebar" scrolling="no" src="sidebar/sidebar.php"></iframe>
```

IDs are here:

```
#sidebar{
    width:56px;
    border:0; 
    height:100%; 
}

#sidebar_active{
    width:150px;
    border:0; 
    height:100%; 
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
var sidebar = $('#sidebar');

    sidebar.hoverIntent(function(){
        sidebar.attr('id','sidebar_active');
    }, function(){
        sidebar.attr('id','sidebar');
    });
})
```

Here is the working link http://jsfiddle.net/asadalikanwal/usL4a8xj/

Comment: `#sidebar{
    width:56px; 
    border:0px;
}

#sidebar_active{
    width:150px;
    border:0px;
}
`
Turns out border was causing the problem. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Yup just add frameborder="0" in iframe tag

http://jsfiddle.net/asadalikanwal/usL4a8xj/1/